# Java Hiding string value

Tags: java, string

Is there any way to hide value in a string while displaying it? Now the challenge is that I want to populate a date field(which accepts only date values) with a empty "  /    " value(which asks  the end user to fill in the mm/yyyy format).Is there any way to mask string value with a blank space ,so that I can use a

```
String s="11/1111";
s.****??
dateField.setText(s);
```

At the end both that validator and the end user should be happy :).your inputs appreciated.

Comment: This should be property of the container/field. What's the type of your `dateField`?

Comment: Can you show more code? Which type is dateField?

Comment: Actually its a swing project. This datefield is a component inherited from Jtext field.The thing is that I cannot change any other character of the date edit field ,but i want to  populate that field with a blank date, somehow and this should happen in the panel level.If i try to parse a blank value im getting this java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "  /    "

Comment: You can change the date for a label in the panel and you can put in anything you want.